# Flutter - Firebase (QuerySnapshot) (Not able to get documents from firebase) *After the update of flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am working on the notification page of an app that was working fine before the update of the flutter. After updating flutter and some packages that same code is not able to get documents from firebase and not showing any errors.

```
    class _NotificationPageState extends State<NotificationPage> {
  retrieveNotifications() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await activityFeedReference
        .doc(currentUser.id)
        .collection("feedItems")
        .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
        .limit(60)
        .get();

    List<NotificationItem> notificationsItems = [];

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      notificationsItems.add(NotificationItem.fromDocument(document));
    });

    return notificationsItems;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: retrieveNotifications(),
          builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
              return circularProgress();
            }
            return ListView(
              children: dataSnapshot.data,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Logs**

```
D/skia    ( 1858): Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 1858): ------------------------
D/skia    ( 1858): Errors:
D/skia    ( 1858):
I/umar.travelboo( 1858): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 21394(884KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 4175KB/4692KB, paused 515us total 165.557ms
```

Comment: Please mention logs here

Comment: logs ? sorry new to this

Comment: Flutter logs from console